# using substring-before and substring to check contains '.'

Tags: xslt

i've the below peice of my xml.

```
<para>As set out in paragraph 2.006 above it is also possible that a Hong Kong Court may appoint an overseas liquidator to act in a Hong Kong liquidation provided that the court is satisfied as to his suitability to act. </para>
```

here i want to check if there is a space before '.' and before 2(2 places before '.'), i use the below statement to get it but unable to get it, but it is not working. please let me know how do i modify this.

```
 <xsl:if test=" contains(substring-before(substring(current(),2,1),'.'),' ')"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that this is what you like to do:

```
     <xsl:if test=" contains( 
           substring (current(),
                      string-length(
                            substring-before(current(), '.')
                       ) -1,2)
                ,' ')">
```

This test the last two character before the first dot "." if they containing a space. (I'm not sure if the test should be done for the last two or three character. But this is easy to adapt)